# ERROR ITMS-9000 while upload ipa to app store using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5

I am trying to upload ipa file to app store and i found following error.[image]

I have try to search but won't able to find any solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Under the GENERAL -> TARGET my app name is blank some how. So by creating new project it solve my problem.